# PHP : Missing error log on my live server (Cpanel)

Tags: php, codeigniter, error-handling, cpanel

i have a project running on php 5.6 version developed using CodeIgniter,
I am trying to send email wit attachment using PHPmailer email goes fine but if I add attachment it gives me

> site is currently unable to handle this request.HTTP ERROR 500

Now the problem is I cant find out error_log on my server : Below is php.ini inside my root folder that is site.com/beta

```
allow_url_fopen = On
allow_url_include = Off
asp_tags = Off
display_errors = On
enable_dl = Off
file_uploads = On
max_execution_time = 30000
max_input_time = 60000
max_input_vars = 1000
memory_limit = 512M
post_max_size = 30M
session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440
session.save_path = "/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php56"
upload_max_filesize = 20M
zlib.output_compression = Off
```

i tried added below 2 lines at the end of the file but it gives no result

```
error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);
error_log = /var/log/php.errors
```

i tried to update

> $config['log_threshold'] = 4

`  and 1 but still error_log did not show up ,

can anyone help me how can i find it since its really frustrating for me atm after spending so much time

Comment: The errors can end up in the web servers error log, so check there.

Comment: i checked under Metrics insider cpanel, but there are no current errors for this

Comment: I don't know how cpanel works, but if that's what you're using, you should mention it in your question (and add that tag) so people get the full picture.

Comment: sorry about that , just added that